# Texture Paint not Applying to Render Preview

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, node-editor, image

I UV unwrapped my object (an eye), and applied a texture to it. Because the texture doesn't match up perfectly on both sides of the sphere, I'm left with a seam. I tried fixing it using the clone tool in Texture Paint, and it seems to work fine when I look at it through solid mode. 
[image]
However, when I switch to rendered mode, there is no change in the texture. I've save the texture image already. I'm not sure how to make it appear? 
[image]

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfEyhPXsOCM) to create the eye, then modified the nodes to try and get the texture in. The texture wasn't explained in the video, so I just tried to piece it together. Here are my nodes:
[image]

I'm new to blender and this is only the second project I've worked on, so I'm still unfamiliar with the program functions. If anyone has an easier way to suggest adding the veins, I would really appreciate it!

Here is the file: [image]

Comment: Could you provide the .blend file? (Don't forget to pack the images into the file)

Comment: @fourtwo Stupid question, how do I post the blend file? I can't seem to find an option to add it to the post...

Comment: Not at all, I guess you'll have to share a link from a third party like Google drive or similar..       https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: Awesome thanks! I added it to the bottom of the post.

Comment: If you look at the image editor menu you'll see a little star next to the "Image" menu, this means that the texture hasn't been saved.  The render engine is likely using the image on disk, so you'd need to save it first. If this resolves it I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: That is true, just assumed you have saved the new edit (that what I understood from the post)

Comment: well.. after looking at the file @Merlin was right, you have to edit all your texture files and *save* them, blender doesn't automatically saves the edits.  after that it shows in render view,   (also, better not having two output nodes)